# How do you get to continue the mission “Elder Knowledge”, if you’ve already asked Urag gro-Shub about the elder scroll in the Dawnguard DLC?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I'm doing the mission “Elder Knowledge” to get the elder scroll, but since I’ve already asked him about an elder scroll because of the Dawnguard DLC, he doesn’t have the option to talk to him about it, but the mission won’t continue. I’ve tried closing the game (on PS4) but he still doesn’t have the option. (In Skyrim: Special Edition)

Comment: My suggestion would be to look online where the elder scroll is and retrieve it

Answer (score 3):

From the [Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Elder_Knowledge), this appears to be a known bug:

> If all of the quests are completed for the College of Winterhold before having talked with Urag gro-Shub about the Elder Scrolls, there will be no text option to ask for the books about the location of an Elder Scroll. The proper text option has a slim possibility to appear after all available chat options have been selected. This bug appears if the Dragonborn has already spoken to Septimus Signus before talking to Urag. If Septimus Signus has already been talked to, it is possible to skip talking to Urag and continue on to the Tower of Mzark

Usually, as is the case suggested in the excerpt, you can simply move on to the next part of the mission, and force the progression of the questline.

Comment: For the record: The main quest literally does not care about talking to Urag at all. You can go straight to Septimus from the beginning of the game, and obtain the Elder Scroll before you have even completed Dragon Rising or started Dawnguard. Both the main quest and the Dawnguard quest will automatically progress correctly if you do this, assuming Dawnguard is installed (I have no idea what happens if Dawnguard is not installed).